# Integration Test: API controller failed to call another controller via ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem getting an API controller to call another API controller within the same project.

Specifically, the integration project is able to call a controller in the production project, and the controller will make another call to a dummy controller within the same project, but the first controller failed with internal server error.

However, the first controller can call google.com.

Please note that it works when the production project is hosted via either console or windows services. It only happens when tests in integration project run.

The production project is an ASP.NET CORE Web API project v2.1, and the integration test project, v2.1 via xUnit by following below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Integration project with xUnit below:

```
public class RetryPolicyTests: IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public RetryPolicyTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("http://localhost:1234/api/v1/Book/")]        
        public async Task Test(string url)
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act           

            var body = "{}";
            using (var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                // Assert
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //Failed here with internal server error
                Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    (int) (response.StatusCode));
            }
        }
    }
```

BookController

```
  [ApiVersion("1")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BookController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public BookController(ILog logger , IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;            
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post()
        {           
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string body = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var url = "http://localhost:1234/api/v1/Author/"
                using (var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {                    
                    var _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                    var s = _httpClient.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;  //works here

                    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);   //internal server error
                     var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    return StatusCode((int)statusCode);
                }

            }      
        }

    }
```

AuthorController

```
 [ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]        
public class AuthorController : ControllerBase
{
    ILog _logger;

    public AuthorController(ILog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }

}
```

It works if integration test hits directly at Author controller.

Error:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at IntegrationTests.xUnit.RetryPolicy.RetryPolicyTests.Test(String url) in C:\IntegrationTests.xUnit\RetryPolicy\RetryPolicyTests.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Result Message: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

**Update**

Please note that after integration test hits the first controller and before hits the second controller, I tried to send the same data to the first controller via external tools, like Postman, or fiddler. But all controllers are not available to external tool, unlike if it is hosted on console or Windows service (In this case, all controllors can process requests).

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5132

**Update**

I upgraded to 2.2, issue still exists

**Update**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at Controllers.BookController.Post() in C:\src\Controllers\BookController.cs:line 84} System.Exception {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException}

InnerException {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)} System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}
```

Comment: How do you set up your Test Server? You may wanna have look here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681935/teststartup-contained-in-a-testproject-that-inherits-from-api-startup-contained?noredirect=1#comment94225470_53681935

Comment: what is logger capturing a 500 is pretty generic

Comment: @kos I will try that. thx

Comment: @saj, yes, I cannot see detailed error.

Comment: @Kos, Below is for MVC only? My project doesn't use MVC. services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddApplicationPart(typeof(ValuesController).Assembly);

Comment: I upgraded to 2.2, issue still exists

Comment: For `500`, it usually means there is error in code. While debugging, will `AuthorController.Post` be hit? Try to debug your code line by line. Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @TaoZhou the AuthorController Post method is not hit. But it works without integration test. So I think it is integration issue.

Comment: @Pingpong Look at mine soulution in there. You don’t need use mvc.

Comment: @Pingpong can you post here your test server configurations? I don’t see anything wrong in your tests or controllers so it’s more likely to be configuration issue. Make sure you are setting up correctly the path to your pofiject root directory and base url!

Comment: please see exception updated on the opening ticket.

Comment: @Kos Test server configurations? I don't have any that I know.

Comment: @Pingpong It should be in that WebApplicationFactory

Comment: @kos Both controllers are using the same url: http://localhost:1234/, the default setting in WebApplicationFactory is used, I don't set any values.

Comment: @Pingpong Well, so in these default configuration where the web host is getting configured. Can you make sure directory root path is correct, is it pointing  to your web project folder ?

Comment: @Kos, I am new to ASP.NET Core, not sure how to check, because I showed all the code already. The fact that the request comes through the first controller means the directory is correct. Because the second controller resides at the same folder as the first controller.

Comment: @Pingpong Can you try to comment out ReadToEnd() maybe that content  “{}” is the problem. l don’t see where else it could fail then ...